# jQuery argument suddely changes into n.Event object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown on my page,which selected value I take like this:

```
<select id="campaign" class="form-control">
      <option>Choose campaign</option>
      <option value="createCampaign">Create new campaign</option>
      <?php while($row=$resultForCampaigns->fetch_assoc()){
        $campaignName=$row['campaign_name'];
        echo "<option value=$campaignName>$campaignName</option>";
    }?>
</select>
var campaign = $('#campaign option:selected').val();
```

But when I'm passing that same `campaign` value as a argument of new function, and do `console.log(campaign)` it says:[image]

Here is the whole code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#campaign').change(function() {
    var campaign = $('#campaign option:selected').val();
    console.log(campaign);
    if (campaign != 'Choose campaign') {
      console.log(campaign);
      $('#deleteCampaign').click(function(campaign) {
        console.log(campaign);
        var r = confirm("Are you absolutely sure you want to delete selected campaign?");
        if (r == true) {
          var data = {};
          data.action2 = "deleteCampaign";
          data.campaign = campaign;

          $.ajax({
            url: "../includes/adapter.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: data,
            async: true,
            success: function() {
              if (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#poruka').append('<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> You have successfully deleted campaign!</div>');

              } else {
                $('#poruka').append('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Failure!</strong> Something went wrong with deleting your campaign! Please try again</div>');
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

So, `console.log(campaign)` after click on `$('#deleteCampaign')` turns value of `campaign` from one that I've gave it, to one that picture represents. Really don't know what's going on, so If anyone could explain me how to get correct value inside function that is tiggered by click, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `campaign` is redefined when you use the same name as a function argument in a lower scope.
Variables are scoped to functions, and function arguments are considered variables, it would be the same as doing

```
var something = 'stuff';

function go() {
     something = 'other stuff';

     console.log(something); // obviously "other stuff"
}
```

The first argument for the `click` function in jQuery is the event object, you can't pass in anything else.

All you have to do is just remove the argument.

```
var campaign = $('#campaign option:selected').val();

$('#deleteCampaign').click(function() {
    console.log(campaign);   // still the value
```

Comment: Yeah, that helped. So it's all matter of scope. Thanks for helping me on this one :)

Comment: Yes, it's a matter of scope, and using the same variable name for different variables